# Magento 2 : Extend/Override files in theme

Tags: magento2

I have a question :

What if I add the requirejs-config.js file in app/design/frontend/Themename/theme/Magento_Catalog/requirejs-config.js

Does this extends the `Magento_Catalog` or override the whole file?
I mean it won't call the core module's file but will call the theme file?

I want to know the same scenario with phtml & layout files.

Can anybody explain?

Thanks

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Layout files like catalog_product_view.xml usually extend. You can put layout files in a specisl directory to make them override.

Theme phtml & js files override.